# Localize DateTime in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I have the following datetime stored in SQL Server in remote host.

```
2016-11-01 14:46:26.133
//The above date time has been taken from below - 
DateTime utcDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
TimeZoneInfo BangladeshTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Bangladesh Standard Time");
now = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDateTime, BangladeshTimeZone);
```

I am reading this in C# MVC app and sending to client as json via AJAX -

```
 List<VisitInfo> attendance = db.Query<VisitInfo>(selectSql).ToList();
 return Json(new { result = "success", data = attendance }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

In client-

```
<td>' + $.date(new Date(parseJsonDate(item.VisitDate))) + '</td>
```

I have the following helper functions to process json date-

```
$.date = function (dateObject) {
    var d = new Date(dateObject);
    var day = d.getDate();
    var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    if (day < 10) {
        day = "0" + day;
    }

    var amPm = "am";
    var hours = d.getHours();

    if (hours >= 12) {
        amPm = "pm";
        hours = hours - 12;
    }

    if (month < 10) {
        month = "0" + month;
    }
    var date = day + "-" + month + "-" + year + " " + hours + ":" + d.getMinutes() + " " + amPm;
    return date;
};

function parseJsonDate(jsonDateString) {
    return new Date(parseInt(jsonDateString.replace('/Date(', '')));
}
```

It works fine when I run this on my development machine. But When it runs on remote server (on different time zone), it shows different time.

Date time shown when run on local PC - `01-11-2016 2:46 pm`. And I would like to use this everywhere.

Date time shown when run from server - `02-11-2016 1:46 am`.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you strip off the UTC offset during the communication to the server or while writing to the database, so when you get the date/time back, your browser thinks that it gets UTC time, so it adds another local offset, hence the time shift.

Btw, you might benefit from using momentjs (http://momentjs.com/docs/). If you do Your date method could be changed to something like this:

```
moment(dateObject).format("DD-mm-YYYY hh:mm a")
```

This library provides a wide range of functionality when working with dates.